# Como recuperar el valor de un map

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo un problema que no se cómo resolver y es que el Map llamado combi que está declarado de manera static lo relleno en el metodo onComplete, en el log con las "AAAAAAAAAA" me aparece que el tamaño del Map en ese momento es 1 y eso es correcto, pero a la hora de retornar el Map, me lo devuelve vacío, el log con las "BBBBBBBBBBBBBB" aparece que tiene 0.

```
public static Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> dameCombinaciones() {
    db.collection("combinaciones")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        int cont = 0;
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                           Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();
                            combi.put(cont,data);

                            Log.d(TAG,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA: "+combi.size());

                            cont++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
    Log.d(TAG,"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB: "+combi.size());
    return combi;
}
```

Espero alguna solución, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los *listeners* de Firebase son asíncronos. Significa que cuando el código llega donde tienes lo `B` nada te asegura que el objeto ya se haya llenado dentro del `onComplete`.

Una forma de resolver esto sería creando un nuevo método, al cual llamarías desde dentro del `onComplete()` pasándole el dato.

Por ejemplo:

```
public static void dameCombinaciones() {
    db.collection("combinaciones")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        int cont = 0;
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {    
                           Map<String, Object> data = document.getData();
                            combi.put(cont,data);    
                            Log.d(TAG,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA: "+combi.size());    
                            cont++;
                        }
                        /*
                           Aquí no habrá duda de que el onComplete ocurrió
                           Y podrás pasar con seguridad el objeto al método para leerlo
                        */
                        readData(combi);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

}

/*
    El método que llamarás desde dentro del onComplete
    y en el cual podrás leer los datos
*/

private static void readData(Map<Integer, Map<String, Object>> combi) {
    Log.d(TAG,"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB: "+combi.size());
}
```

---

### Recomendación

Hace pocos años Android está recomendando la escritura de código basado en una arquitectura limpia (clean arquitectura) y para ello ha creado una serie de componentes.

Para el caso de Firebase se recomienda también pasar el código a este tipo de arquitectura. Si te interes al tema, puedes leer [esta entrada publicada en el blog de Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html), donde se explican las ventajas de hacer esto y se muestra un ejemplo para migrar el código.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, ya funciona, seguiré tu recomendación e intentaré pasar el código a la arquitectura más limpia.